# Find matching column values to calculate percentage change between values in another column

Tags: r

I'm looking for help on how to approach this problem in R. I have a single data frame with hydrological data.

climate change scenarios where ref is the reference conditions and nf_4.5 and nf_8.5 are future projections ( I actually have 2 more future projections in my actual data):

```
scenario <- c("ref", "ref", "ref","nf_4.5","nf_4.5","nf_4.5","nf_8.5","nf_8.5","nf_8.5")
```

models with different climate data (9 of them, in the simplified version below just 3)

```
 model <- c("mod.1", "mod.2", "mod.3","mod.1", "mod.2", "mod.3","mod.1", "mod.2", "mod.3" )
```

several different river subbasins named as numbers (18 of them, in the simplyfied version below just 1)

```
 subbasin <- c("910", "910","910", "910","910", "910","910", "910","910" )
```

indicator values that I collected.

```
 indicator <- c("4.5", "5.6", "4.8", "3.4", "3.9", "2.9", "1.7", "1.5", "2.1")
    
    test <- data.frame(scenario, model, subbasin, indicator)
```

My goal is to calculate the percentage change between the indicator value (indicator column) in future projections in relation to reference conditions (scenario column). In order to do that, I need to also match the values in the columns “model” and “subbasin” so that I'm looking at the same subbasin and model.
I’m hoping to obtain a data table similar to this:

```
scenario_change <- c("nf_4.5","nf_4.5","nf_4.5","nf_8.5","nf_8.5","nf_8.5")
model_2 <- c("mod.1", "mod.2", "mod.3","mod.1", "mod.2", "mod.3" )
subbasin_2 <- c("910", "910","910", "910","910", "910" )
perc_change <- c( '-24.4', '-30.4', '-39.6', '-62.2', '-73.2', '-56.3')
result <- data.frame(scenario_change, model_2, subbasin_2, perc_change)
```

from that I’m planning to draw a box plot like this one (example):

[image]

I know how to create a box plot but first I feel that I need to restructure this data, but I can’t grasp how to obtain the desired result data frame, can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` functions from the **`tidyverse`**:

```
library(tidyverse)


test$indicator <- as.numeric(test$indicator)


test %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = scenario, values_from = indicator) %>%
  mutate_at(c("nf_4.5", "nf_8.5"), ~(. - ref)/ref) %>%
  select(-ref) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("nf"),
               names_to = "scenario_change",
               values_to = "perc_change")

#   model subbasin scenario_change perc_change
# 1 mod.1 910      nf_4.5               -0.244
# 2 mod.1 910      nf_8.5               -0.622
# 3 mod.2 910      nf_4.5               -0.304
# 4 mod.2 910      nf_8.5               -0.732
# 5 mod.3 910      nf_4.5               -0.396
# 6 mod.3 910      nf_8.5               -0.562
```